# Optimal way to achieve setmaxresults in springdatajpa with hql query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, hql

Since limit is not supported in @query of spring, we need alternative way for this other than pagination query param

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query(" select something so where so.id>50 order by so.created desc")
    @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.annotations.FETCH_SIZE" , value = "1"))
optionam<something> findlatestSomething();
```

Comment: fetch size is not the same as max results.

Comment: Is there any other better way for max result ? I just need to restrict max result to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(" select something s where s.id = select max(so.id) something so order by so.id desc")
optionam<something> findlatestSomething();
```

Comment: You already submitted an answer two days ago. What's the purpose of posting a second answer? If this resolves an issue with your first answer, you should just edit your first answer. By contrast, if this provides an alternative approach that might be preferable in certain situations, it'd be useful to explain what those situations are. Though, even in that case, you'd usually just put these options in the same answer.

Comment: I have submitted multiple answers for same query. I agreed that i may add all different answer together. later part only I learned that another approach. so that shared as another answer. hope you got it.

Comment: It still doesn't help me understand the difference between these. Which is preferred? Under what circumstances?